# In Dominion Intrigue does Bridge Stack with Itself

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

If I play the card "Bridge" twice, which says to reduce the cost of items by 1 (minimum of 0), does this reduce the cost of all items by 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed it does.  From the rulebook:

**The effect is cumulative; if you Throne Room a Bridge, all cards will cost 2 coins less this turn.**

Obviously the effect will still be cumulative if you just play two Bridges in one turn!

Comment: And same with effects from Coppersmith, Quarry, Hoard, Goons, etc.

Comment: Goons doesn't perfectly stack with Throne Room and King's Court.  The money and buys stack, but the +VP per buy do not.

Comment: @Rob:  Really?  I guess my group has been playing it wrong.  I actually looked it up if you're right or not, and... indeed you are.  However, playing two Goons separately stacks the +VP.